Warning: Could Not Fetch Resource running flow::flow_doc in R
I have an internal package "RedTor".  When I execute flow:flow_doc it creates warnings of the forms

[WARNING] Could not fetch resource exp_n.png

Where n ranges from 1 to 116.  It produces warnings for the unexported functions as well.
It also produces the message:
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test.knit.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandocdc1c297c7c78.html --lua-filter "C:\Users\xer09\ONEDRI~2\REDTOR~1\Research\R\WIN-LI~1\3.6\RMARKD~1\RMARKD~1\lua\PAGEBR~1.LUA" --lua-filter "C:\Users\xer09\ONEDRI~2\REDTOR~1\Research\R\WIN-LI~1\3.6\RMARKD~1\RMARKD~1\lua\LATEX-~1.LUA" --embed-resources --standalone --variable bs3=TRUE --section-divs --table-of-contents --toc-depth 3 --variable toc_float=1 --variable toc_selectors=h1,h2,h3 --variable toc_collapsed=1 --variable toc_smooth_scroll=1 --variable toc_print=1 --template "C:\Users\xer09\ONEDRI~2\REDTOR~1\Research\R\WIN-LI~1\3.6\RMARKD~1\rmd\h\DEFAUL~1.HTM" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable theme=bootstrap --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url=https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --include-in-header "C:\Users\xer09\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQL9R0h\rmarkdown-strdc1ce3446b5.html"
Any ideas what causes this and how to resolve?
